# Can I force a compilation error inside an user control?

Tags: c#, winforms

Example: 
I have an user control with 1 property (that one editable through Property Grid) called "Title".
There is a way to throw an compile-time exception if the property "Title" is empty? Or all design-time properties is optional?

Comment: AFAIK, this is not possible

Comment: How about requiring it in the constructor?

Comment: It's a user control, the constructor call is generated automatically. I need to use a parameterless constructor.

Comment: http://www.sharpcrafters.com/ (postsharp) could help you. But do you want to enforce your developers to fill that out. Maybe simply enforce coding guidelines and a 5$ pot for everyone forgetting them ;-)

Comment: Why don't you use a default value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way at compile time to ensure a particular property is set. You can use the [#error](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/x5hedts0%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) directive to cause a compile time error or [#warning](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/963th5x3.aspx) for a compile time warning if code is compiled but this is not what you want.

There are two ways of ensuring a particular property or method is set. The first is to require it in a constructor or check that it has been set in a subsequent method or property. This is a runtime check, not compile time and, as you say, you have certain restrictions in a UserControl.

The second way is to use a code analysis tool like [FXCop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb429476%28v=vs.80%29.aspx). You could write a custom rule that identifies all instances of your UserControl and ensures the property has been set on all instances. It may also be possible with [Roslyn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/roslyn) or PostSharp but I am not familiar enough with those tools to say so.

The problem with code analysis tools like FXCop is there is a rather steep learning curve. Programming languages are complex and these tools need to expose the complexity. My recommendation is use a default value like "insert title here" or, in the unlikely even that there is no suitable default, throw an exception when the control is rendered with a descriptive message.

See [Good way to ensure that a property on a UserControl gets set?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3460362/good-way-to-ensure-that-a-property-on-a-usercontrol-gets-set) for a similar case.