# check required property for user control at design time like id or runat Attribute

Tags: asp.net, user-controls

I want to create user control to show data at different place and I have three option to display data.

1. Table
2. XML
3. Json

I want to create a user control with required property "DisplayStyle". if user forget to initialize the value of property then it should give us a compile time error.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I force a compilation error inside an user control?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14121654/can-i-force-a-compilation-error-inside-an-user-control)

Comment: Then what is the approach of Microsoft when we are not declaring id or runat property for any control.